# Connect to database using sql server authentication programatically

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

How can I connect to database using sql server authentication programmatically in c# winforms? I mean i created a login named loginTesting with a loginTesting as user in sql server 2012. I want to access that login in c# by accepting user inputs from textbox. Thanks.

Comment: Outside "use simply string manipulation to construct a connection string that contains the username and password entered by the user"? Do you ahve any programming experience at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on Answer 1, if you'd like to test your usernames/passwords based on user input you could use the SqlConnectionStringBuilder object as shown in this example:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
connectionString.ConnectionString = @"data source=.;initial catalog=master;";
connectionString.UserID = "username";
connectionString.Password = "password";

using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ConnectionString))
{

}
```

Comment: It's working and all but i can't use this in my other forms. I did something like this:

`connectionString.ConnectionString = @"data source=myDataSource.;initial catalog=master;";
connectionString.UserID = txtUser.text;
connectionString.Password = txtPassword.text;`

Comment: Try creating a database class which contains a static method to get your database connection and then use that in your forms for consistency for example:

Comment: `class Database
    {
        public static SqlConnection CreateSqlConnection(string username, string password)
        {
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlConnectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            sqlConnectionString.ConnectionString = @"data source=myDataSource.;initial catalog=master;"; ;
            sqlConnectionString.UserID = username;
            sqlConnectionString.Password = password;

            return new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString.ConnectionString);
        }
    }`

Comment: Then in your forms call the database CreateSqlConnection method and pass in your username/password values like this:

`using (var sqlConnection = Database.CreateSqlConnection("username", "password"))
{
   //Do something 
}`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the class SqlConnectionStringBuilder to construct the connection string that you will need for a SqlConnection object:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder scsBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
scsBuilder.UserID = "username";
scsBuilder.Password = "password";
scsBuilder.DataSource = "servername or ip address";
scsBuilder.InitialCatalog = "databasename";
scsBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = false;

using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(scsBuilder.ConnectionString))
{
  // perform your SQL tasks
}
```

Further reading here:
[SqlConnectionStringBuilder Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[SqlConnection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new SQLConnection (and clear it up once you've used it).

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   // Do something
}
```

The tricky bit is getting the correct connection string, but fortunately there are resources to help. Checkout [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) to find a connection string that looks like it should work, plug in your credentials/server etc and you're good to go.